# lodash unable to flatten array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to unnest an array currently using this code:

```
var mapped = _.flatMap(payload, ({GroupId,Learners}) =>
    _.map(Learners, LearnerId => ({GroupId:GroupId,Learner:LearnerId}))
);
```

however the value return still produces and array:
e.g

```
{"GroupId":1246574,"Learner":{"Forename":"George","Surname":Bob",,"StartDate":"2020-09-01","EndDate":"2021-08-27"}}
```

How can I adapt the script above to only return the GroupId and the Surname?

Example of the payload is here:

```
var payload = 
{
    "GroupId": 1208864,
    "Code": "Ext-StuOth",
    "GroupType": "AcademicHouseGroup",
    "Learners": [
        {
            "LearnerId": 245218,
            "LearnerCode": "2009-0017",
            "Forename": "Sanelisiwe",
            "Surname": "Nazi-Angileh",
            "LearnerGroupLearnerId": 14719301,
            "StartDate": "2017-03-09",
            "EndDate": null
        },
        {
            "LearnerId": 246638,
            "LearnerCode": "2013-0076",
            "Forename": "Randal",
            "Surname": "Bodziarczyk",
            "LearnerGroupLearnerId": 14650361,
            "StartDate": "2017-02-20",
            "EndDate": null
        },
        {
            "LearnerId": 245253,
            "LearnerCode": "109056",
            "Forename": "Wafah",
            "Surname": "Dadisman",
            "LearnerGroupLearnerId": 14650360,
            "StartDate": "2017-02-20",
            "EndDate": null
        }
},{
            "GroupId": 1226419,
            "Code": "U6-JD",
            "GroupType": "RegistrationGroup",
            "Learners": [
                {
                    "LearnerId": 245507,
                    "LearnerCode": "110015",
                    "Forename": "Nahomy",
                    "Surname": "Osburn",
                    "LearnerGroupLearnerId": 14918706,
                    "StartDate": "2017-09-07",
                    "EndDate": "2018-07-31"
                },
                {
                    "LearnerId": 245994,
                    "LearnerCode": "111624",
                    "Forename": "Sherhona",
                    "Surname": "Dobritoiu",
                    "LearnerGroupLearnerId": 14707593,
                    "StartDate": "2017-08-01",
                    "EndDate": "2018-07-31"
                }
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (including in- and expected output) that shows the actual problem.

Comment: what is your payload?

Comment: ive added the payload example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = _.flatMap(payload, ({GroupId, Learners}) => {
    return _.map(Learners, learner => ({GroupId, LearnerId: learner.LearnerId}))
})
```

Comment: hopping playload = [..yourgiven json]

Comment: This produces a missing value.

Comment: what was missing

Answer (score 0):

### It is not an array, it is a [JSON object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) (that contains arrays)

You can access access the elements as following:

```js
  console.log(payload.GroupId);
  var learners = payload.Learners;
  learners.forEach(function(learner){    
  console.log(learner.Surname);
```